# Cannot POST data - Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a small application in which i am posting just one field name district in database using php mysql - my app.js file has code -

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])
.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.insertdata = function(){
console.log($scope.district);
$http.post('insert.php',{'district':$scope.district})
.success(function(data)
{
console.log("Done");
})
} });
```

and index.html has

```
<body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="district"/>
<input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="insertdata()"/>
</form>
```

and insert.php has:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$districtname = mysql_escape_string($data->district);
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
mysql_query("Insert into districtapp (districtname) Values ('".$districtname."')");
```

I have installed codova whitelist and added these lines :

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

I run app by ionic serve and get :

Error : POST http://192.168.2.152:8100/insert.php 404 Not Found

Can anyone please help me to solve this Posting issue?

Comment: Can you access the URL in your browser? Or can you POST to it with curl?

Comment: Have you included the whitelist plugin? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Maybe have a closer look into your remote debugger, which headers are set, what the exact return values are...

Comment: return values of header?

Comment: Is it possible if i upload my application on skydrive or dropbox so you can look into issue -

Comment: You could create a plnkr

Comment: ok hold then please - just few mins

Comment: @23tux problem is posting issue how can u see this on plnkr? i am sorry i am new to all these -

Comment: Are you sure http://192.168.2.152 is your server IP? can you open that url from the phone browser?

Comment: @jcesarmobile if i use `$http.get` - this works fine and retrieves all code from file but `$http.post` is not working . yes its the IP

Answer (score 0):

This wont work as you are directly posting to the insert.php file on localhost. The Ionic framework expects the PHP file to be resident on a different location and it will work if you use absolute URLs to post the data. As you are working on localhost, here is the solution:

1. Create another folder in your `wamp/www` folder in your localhost and name it anything you like, for example: `myapp`. Put your `insert.php` file in this folder.
2. Now change `$http.post('insert.php',{'district':$scope.district})` to `$http.post('http://localhost/myapp/insert.php',{'district':$scope.district})`

That's it! Now when you try to post the data, you will now notice that `insert.php` file in `myapp` folder will run correctly.

Try it out & let me know how it goes.